# I have a table written in LaTeX but I do not fully understand some symbols can you guys help me?

Tags: tables, symbols

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Minimum Deviation ${D}_m$ from ${R}_1$} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{$}c<{$}|}
\hline
Color & \text{Angle ($^\circ$)} \\ \hline
Red Medium & 48.17 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Yellow & 49.19 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Blue cyan weak & 50.16 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Blue cyan strong & 50.27 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Blue medium & 50.52 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Violet & 51.10 \pm 0.25 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I firstly started writing tables only with `\begin{tabular}` but I was told that it needs to be inside a table environment that's why `\begin{table}` but I do not understand why I couldn't just write with `\begin{tabular}` since despite the errors I had the table I wanted. Would I have serious problems in the future? 
What does `{|c|>{$}c<{$}|}` mean?? I know that if I put `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}` I would have columns with vertical lines. When I put `|r|` this did not work at all!. This notation with `$` I have no idea what it is!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: `tabular` only needs to be in a `table` environment if you want the table to be able to float in the document. If you want the table exactly where you placed it then you don't need to use `table` environment at all.  The `{|c|>{$}c<{$}|}` is making the second column to automatically be be in math mode. That is why you needed `\text` and could say `48.17 \pm 0.25` instead of `$48.17 \pm 0.25$` which is what you would need if you wanted this text in your document elsewhere (outside of the second column).

Comment: A `table` environment is not mandatory but move your table to the best place within the text  "automagically" (usually, not where you left) or more or less "manually" (adding some options), allow numbered captions (try add `\caption{text}`just above `\begin{tabular}`) and allow cross-references.). You will loved LaTeX because the floating environments like this or `figure`!  The `>{$}c<{$}` hieroglyphic, is only a dirty trick for lazy people. You can survive using  `c` (better than `|c|`) and writing twice `$` in each cell.

Comment: @PeterGrill An answer?

Answer (score 4):

`tabular` only needs to be in a `table` environment if you want the `table` to be able to float in the document. If you want the table exactly where you placed it then you don't need to use `table` environment at all.

The `{|c|>{$}c<{$}|}` is making the second column to automatically be in math mode. That is why you needed `\text` and could say `48.17 \pm 0.25` instead of `$48.17 \pm 0.25$`, which is what you would need if you wanted this math text in your document elsewhere (outside of the second column).

Also, I think tables look better with [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs). Here is a comparison of your table:

[image]

and the `booktabs` version (where I changed the first column to be `l`eft aligned as well):

[image]

### Notes:

- I used [the `caption` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) for the captions.
- [The `array` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) is needed to be able to set the second column into math mode via the `>{$}c<{$}`.
- [The `amsmath`  package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is needed for the `\text{}` macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ams math}% Needed for \text
\usepackage{array}% For tabluar specification
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\captionof{table}{Minimum Deviation ${D}_m$ from ${R}_1$} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{$}c<{$}|}
\hline
Color & \text{Angle ($^\circ$)} \\ \hline
Red Medium & 48.17 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Yellow & 49.19 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Blue cyan weak & 50.16 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Blue cyan strong & 50.27 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Blue medium & 50.52 \pm 0.25 \\ \hline
Violet & 51.10 \pm 0.25 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\par}

\par\bigskip\noindent
With the \verb|booktabs| package:

{\centering
\captionof{table}{Minimum Deviation ${D}_m$ from ${R}_1$} 
\begin{tabular}{l >{$}c<{$}}\toprule
Color & \text{Angle ($^\circ$)} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
Red Medium & 48.17 \pm 0.25 \\ 
Yellow & 49.19 \pm 0.25 \\ 
Blue cyan weak & 50.16 \pm 0.25 \\ 
Blue cyan strong & 50.27 \pm 0.25 \\ 
Blue medium & 50.52 \pm 0.25 \\ 
Violet & 51.10 \pm 0.25 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\par}

\end{document}
```